# How to check custom fields from functions.php

Tags: custom-field, menus

I'm trying to hide certain menu items based on the custom fields on a page. I could use CSS or a script to hide the items, that's not the problem. What I don't know is how I can check the custom fields (if field empty then hide item) in my functions.php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you need to hide the element completely, as in "never display it", or if you need to hide it conditionally with JavaScript-- say, to get a toggle effect. Either case is similar and would use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

To conditionally display the data use something like:

```
$m = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'my_meta_key');
if(!empty($m)) {
  echo '<div>your data</div>';
}
```

If you want something that you can toggle with JavaScript use:

```
$m = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'my_meta_key');
$str = '<div %s>your data</div>';
if(!empty($m)) {
  $str = sprintf($str,'class="'.$m.'"'); 
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of get_post_meta() but the problem was that it didn't return anything. I did some digging and found that I had to hook into a function that loads later. I used "shutdown", which worked fine for me.